# Sort data display last 30 days data with foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, sorting

i will sort data display last 30 days data with foreach with PHP.

This my code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
       echo  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-'. $i .' days')).'<br>';
   }
```

this is the result:

```
2021-10-07
2021-10-06
2021-10-05
2021-10-04
2021-10-03
2021-10-02
2021-10-01
2021-09-30
2021-09-29
2021-09-28
2021-09-27
2021-09-26
2021-09-25
2021-09-24
2021-09-23
2021-09-22
2021-09-21
2021-09-20
2021-09-19
2021-09-18
2021-09-17
2021-09-16
2021-09-15
2021-09-14
2021-09-13
2021-09-12
2021-09-11
2021-09-10
2021-09-09
2021-09-08
```

Then I want to sort the data from the oldest date to the new date. From **2021-09-08** to **2021-10-07**.

how to do it, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out

```
for($i = 30; $i >= 0; $i--) {
       echo  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-'. $i .' days')).'<br>';
}
```